# How to share article on facebook with proper og metas when the article has custom GET parameters?

Tags: php, facebook

so an article:

```
www.example.com/test
```

with:

```
og:title = 1
og:description = 2
```

and it gets shared well, title and descriptions prints well. But when I have this:

```
www.example.com/test?parameter=12345
```

with:

```
og:title = a
og:description = b
```

debugger will still output 1, 2 instead of a, b.
But the redirect page indicates something unexpecteds:

> Input URL       => [www.example.com/test?parameters=1235](http://www.example.com/test?parameters=1235)

> og:url Meta Tag => [www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test)

as if it intentionall trims the parameters

Comment: Facebook follows whatever URL _you_ specify as `og:url`. You need to specify `http://www.example.com/test?parameter=12345` as `og:url` here, if you want Facebook to consider _that_ to be the actual URL of this share. (And of course they will be treated as two separate Open Graph objects then. Reactions and shares will be counted for each of those two URLs individually.)

Comment: yea if could be, I realized I had that og:url too.